# Java Spring MongoDB @TextIndexed annotation not creating index in existing db

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, annotations

I have collection in MongoDB and I'm trying to generate text indexes using Spring annotations (@TextIndexed). I'm not creating database on application start, it's already created.

Problem is - indexes are not being added to my database.

Does annotation work only when you creating database after starting application?

Thanks.

Spring v. 4.3.2
MongoDB v. 4.0.1

Answer (score 1):

"**Does annotation work only when you creating the database after starting application**"?

The answer is yes.

If the collection is already created, Spring data does not initialize the indexes.
I had to make something like you want to do and the only solution I found was to do it using the MongoOperations instance.

```
  @Autowired
  private MongoOperations mongoOps;

  @PostConstruct
  public void initializeIndexesInDb(){
    mongoOps.indexOps(YourDocumentClass.class).ensureIndex(new Index().on("fieldName", Direction.ASC));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

on the latest release, you should follow

```
@Configuration
public class Config extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected boolean autoIndexCreation() {
        return true;
    }
    // ...
}
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/845

Comment: +1 thanks, an odd decision though. To make the default action of an annotation to do nothing is quite deceptive. I suspect a few people will add @Indexed expecting it to do what it says and not realise that it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

With the most recent releases of Spring Boot, there should be a property `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation`, which does all the magic. Even on existing databases and collections.